# vue-routerにて、ログアウト時とリロード時の処理を実装したい

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**実装したいこと**
firebaseのログイン、ログアウトの処理を実装し、リロード時はそのままの画面を表示し、ログアウト後に、ログイン画面に遷移しようとすると、ログイン画面に遷移するようにする。
**質問内容**
現在、「ログアウト」、「リロード」、「ログアウト後にログイン中の画面に遷移しようとすると、ログイン画面に遷移する」の3つは、実装できたのですが、リロードをした後に、ログアウトをすると、エラーが発生してしまいました。エラー内容を調べたところ、next関数が同時に1回以上呼ばれていることが原因だと思い、if、elseを使用して実装したのですが、エラーが解消できなかったです。

**発生しているエラー**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/Home" to "/" with a new navigation.
    at createRouterError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2065)
    at createNavigationCancelledError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2047)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2394)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2001)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008)
    at runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2012)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2392)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2001)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2005)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2379)
```

**該当のソースコード**

```
    {
      path: '/Home',
      component: Home,
      beforeEnter: function(to, from, next) {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          console.log(user)
          console.log(!user)
          if (user) {
            next();
          } else {
            next({
              path: '/',
              query: { redirect: to.fullPath },
            });
          }
        })
}
```

どうすればこのエラーが解消できるか検討もついてないです。
ご教授よろしくお願いします

Comment: 「現在、ログアウト、リロード、ログアウト後にログイン中の〜〜」の句読点が分かりづらいのですがこういうことですか？⇨ 「ログアウト、リロード、ログアウトからのログイン, の 3つ」。その上の行も含め, 区切りが分かりやすいようにしてもらうと読みやすくなるかもです。(可能なら「」で括るとかして)

Comment: 了解です。　修正します